# Equivalent to base_report_creator module for custom reports in OpenERP 6.1

Tags: python, odoo

We're migrating our OpenERP installation from version 5.0 to 6.1, and we created several custom reports using the `base_report_creator` module in version 5.0. That module seems to have been removed in version 6.1, so is there an alternative? Are dashboards supposed to replace custom reports? If so, how do I see dashboards in the GTK client?

It looks like someone has started migrating it to version 6.1 on [Google Project Hosting](https://code.google.com/p/my-openerp-addons/source/browse/#svn/trunk/base_report_creator), but it doesn't seem to be finished. Is there anything else in progress, or should I start with that and try to finish the migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the version on [Google Project Hosting](https://code.google.com/p/my-openerp-addons/source/browse/#svn/trunk/base_report_creator) is almost perfect. I copied it to our branch of [custom modules](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~zaber/openobject-addons/zaber-custom/files), and made some minor tweaks to get it working. The biggest hurdles were working around the [access rule changes on the `ir_values` table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14948028/4794), and implementing sorting and searching.